# How to open google play store url in android webview

Tags: android, webview, google-play

I'm gonna open the google play app url on my WebView.
But it says

`This browser is no longer supported. Please use the Google Play Store app to access Google Play.`

I've researched to solve this issue but didn't find the solution. There are ways to open it on another activity but there is no way to open it on WebView yet.

I know I get same message when I'm going to access this URL in normal web browser.

Anyhow is there any solution?

Comment: Why not open it in the app? Are you wanting a desktop view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the user agent : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String))

e.g.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"); // linux desktop mozilla user agent
```

then load the google play.